# On equations with arithmetic functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-functions

Is this good topic for research:

equations with arithmetic functions, for example equations like  $\varphi(n)=\sigma(n)$ or $\varphi(n)+\sigma(n)=d(n)$ ?

If Anyone here have an advise please tell me that.

Comment: These particular equations do not make sense - first one has the only solution $n=1$ while the second has no solutions. In general it depends how much (new) you can say about the equation(s).

Comment: If you solve $\sigma(n)=2n$ I bet this should be awarded by a degree

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev this equation is just an example, I will try to solve new equation, is this topic suitable?

Comment: Whether a topic is suitable for a PhD thesis is a decision to be made by the PhD advisor (or, at the very least, in consultation with the advisor).

Answer (score 1):

From the advices of professors that were provided in comments I think that you should communicate with your advisor. The writing of a PHD thesis is very important and serious, I'm not a professor and I wish you the best. On th other hand I add some ideas in this post.  In my opinion I advice you that the strategy is to study simple things in mathematics, and as a tactic to teach ideas about your research or readings of articles to other persons.

---

None of the ideas that I expose can constitute a thesis (you will always need the **help of a professor**). These ideas now are public (meanwhile that my post is well-received, I will not delete it) and to exploit these ideas it is under the laws of copyright and if I refer well the  Creative Commons license  of Stack Exchange network.

About equations involving arithmetic functions I think that an interesting function is the **Dedekind psi function** $\psi(n)$ see Wikipedia [*Dedekind psi function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_psi_function) and from here try to deduce insteresting equations involving this arithmetic functions and other arithmetic functions. For example recently I've studied equations as $\sigma(\square)=\text{prime}$ and $\varphi(\text{prime})=\square$, in my opinion it should be interesting to study other kind of identities as $$\psi(A)=\frac{1}{\varphi(A)}\left(2(p+1)\right)^2\left(\left(\frac{p+1}{2}\right)^2-1\right)\tag{1}$$
that have the form $\psi(A)\varphi(A)=\square\times(\square-1)$ (therefore here $A$ is a rectangle) for $A=p\cdot(p+2)$, that is in essence the equation by Tomasz Buchert from Theorem 18 in page 23 of [2]. I tried to get characterization of twin primes by using an associated arithmetic billiard, finally for $p=3$ and thus  $p+2=5$ I glue the left and right sides of a rectangle of height $8$ and basis $\psi(A)\varphi(A)=64\cdot 3$ in the shape of a finite cilinder where $\varphi(p\cdot(p+2))$ denotes the number of bounces in arithmetic billiard (if you imagine a small drum crossed by 8 diagonals, if my post is well received I can to scan images and illustrate this post in next days). My belief is that work can be done for other primes constellations (I got it for several sequences in number theory that I can to share in comments). Other idea is try to define equations with more than a variable as I did below my answer of the post on MathOverflow with identifier [*119611*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119611/calculating-n-for-sigma-sigman-n-n-redefined), as you see in my comments that I've edited concerning equations similar than $$\psi(2(\psi(xy)-(x+y-1))-1)=xy\tag{2}$$ in which are involved **two** variables $x$ and $y$. Ancient greeks believed in equations involving integers with up to three variables. As examples of equations involving three variables in $\mathbb{Z}$ I add the following proposition and conjecture for even perfect numbers that have the form $Y=\text{prime}\cdot \square$, I add here the article [*Perfect number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) from Wikipedia (one can to study these kind of statements for odd perfect numbers having this form $\text{prime}\cdot \square$ with $\text{gcd}(\text{prime},\square)=1$, and for intergers of the form $K^K\cdot \{\text{prime of the form }K^K+1\}$, see *A121270* from OEIS or  [4]).

**Proposition.** *Even perfect numbers* $Y=X\cdot Z$ *with* $Z$ *their associated Mersenne prime and* $X$ *the square* $X=2^{p-1}$ *satisfy the equations* $\psi(XZ+YZ)=\psi(XZ)+\psi(YZ)$ *and* $\psi(2XY-XZ)=\psi(2XY)-\psi(XZ)$.

**Conjecture.** *Let* $1\leq X,Y,Z$ *be positive integers such that* $Z$ *is an odd integer,* $X$ *has the form* $X=\frac{Z+1}{2}$, $X\mid Y$ *and* $Z\mid Y$. *A) If the identity* $\psi(XZ+YZ)=6\cdot\left(\frac{X\cdot\psi(YZ)}{Z\cdot\psi(XZ)}\right)^3$ *holds, then* $Y$ *is an even perfect number.* *B) If the identity* $\frac{\psi(2Y)-\psi(Y)}{\psi(XZ)}=\frac{\sigma(X)\sigma(Z)}{2Y}$ *holds, then* $Y$ *is an even perfect number.*

Other idea is to state and study problems about primality or divisibility involving arithmetic functions, as Dedekind psi function (I can to clarify this adding literature in comments).

In the section *Comments* of OEIS for the sequence with identifier [*A001615*](https://oeis.org/A001615) is added the meaning in terms of lattices for the Dedekind psi function. I am trying to attach it to arithmetic billiards, in particular I try to interpret it in terms of the arithmetic billiards that I defined in the post on MathOverflow with identifier **429420** and title *Arithmetic billiards, prime numbers and the Goldbach conjecture*, see [3]. I'm trying to attach more ideas to these diagrams, for example defining refractions (I can to illustrate this idea; other idea is to define from these refractions faces of tetrahedra and cross products of vectors), I did an attempt to think in the definition similar than $\psi_n(x,t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\varphi(n)} e^{i E_k \cdot t}e^{x^k}$ and the operator $L(\psi_n(x,t)):=\psi_n(x,0)= f_n(x)$, I want that these $f_n(x)$ are the functions defined in THEOREM from [1], where here $\varphi(n)$ denotes the Euler's totient function, $i=\sqrt{-1}$ the imaginary unit and the "energy" $E_k$ are constant that I don't know how to define (I did some atempts to define these). Ancient Greeks quantized space and time lapses, but did not know the stationary-action principle/the Principle of Least Action beause they did not quantify the action (I will edit the final version of this parenthesis in the next six months: at my home I'm trying to think in Fermat's principle and Snell's law; the Gudermannian function; the Lambert W-function; the  Apéry's constant and how did Euler get $\zeta(2)$ from $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ in an attempt to made more interesting this kind of billiards).

### References:

[1] David M. Bradley, *A Curious Way to Test for Primes Explained*, Mathematics Magazine Vol. 82, No. 3, June 2009.

[2] Tomasz Buchert, On the twin prime conjecture, Master's thesis, Poznan 2011 (if I refer well the author published it in his website).

[3] Post **429420** with title [*Arithmetic billiards, prime numbers and the Goldbach conjecture*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429420/arithmetic-billiards-prime-numbers-and-the-goldbach-conjecture) asked a month ago in MathOverflow.

[4] Michal Krizek, Florian Luca, and Lawrence Somer, *17 Lectures on Fermat Numbers*, CMS Books in Mathematics, Springer (2001), page 156.

Comment: If you think that this answer is not suitable please add a comment that I can to delete my post in next few hours (I have not Internet at home). If the post is well-recived I can to illustrate some ideas with images that I can to scan and upload as a file to Imgur, and comments here with the formulas, ideas or literature that I evoke in my post, many thanks.

Comment: The equation for Germain primes similar than $(1)$ is for $A=p(2p+1)$ equals to $\psi(A)=\frac{1}{\varphi(A)}(p+1)^2\cdot((2p-1)^2-1)$; the equation corresponding to $A=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ an even perfect number is stated as $\psi(A)=\frac{3}{\varphi(A)}\left(8^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\right)^2\cdot\left(\left(2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\right)^2-1\right)$; if I remember well (!) the equation for $A=2^{2^m}(2^{2^m}+1)$ with $2^{2^m}+1$ a Fermat prime is equals to $\psi(A)=\frac{3}{\varphi(A)}\left(2^{2^m-1+2^{m-1}}\right)^2\cdot\left(\left(2^{2^{m-1}}\right)^2+2\right)$, but there may be typos in this last identitiy

Comment: (1/2) If I can tomorrow I edit a comment with the identifier of an image from Imgur illustrating my claims, and an additional comment with more ideas about problems involving the Dedekind psi function, for example to study inequalities of the form $\psi(an+b)>\psi(cn+d)$ or the distribution of sequences $\left(\frac{\psi(an+b)}{\psi(cn+d)}\right)_{n\geq 1}$ as $n$ grows;

Comment: (2/2)  or congruences $P(n)\psi(Q(n))\equiv 0 \text{ mod }R(n)$ for polynomials $P,Q,R\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$,; or equidistribution problems related to arithmetic sequences involving particular values of $\psi(n)$. Maybe I can to try to motivate equations involving the Dedekind function and factorials $n!$ or Pochhammer symbols but the most important are the comments of professors and in my view my advice in first paragraph. After I will clean these last two comments.

Comment: Many thanks for such nice  answers and advises.
In reality in our university  the advisers propose some suggestions and the studants choose one of them, they are not free in the choosing of topics like other universities,  for that reason I have asked this question because I do not have a time to search more about them by myself. (could I contact you if i need help in this topic and how i do that?, I'm a member here just for some months and I do not know if I can ask a something like that, I am sorry if this question bothered you).

Comment: The question don't bother to me, and thanks you very much for your kindly words. I do not communicate with people about math problems or ideas, my only communicative activity is through posts and comments @Omega If I can I'm going to illustrate the post this afternoon adding a comment with the identifier of a file from Imgur, and I done here this comment thread since one of my posts about billiards is not being well received by the professors of the site, and I prefer don't insist since I like very much such post. I wish the best to you.

Comment: The file has identifier **ziRZYQ4** from Imgur. The figure F1 illustrates the billiard for the cited twin primes pair with $\varphi(p(p+2))$ counting the number of bounces $8$ in finite cylinder of figure F2. The figure F3 illustrates a refraction for $2^{\alpha}||(\varphi(r)+\varphi(q))$ with $r=3$ and $q$ equals to the prime number $11$ and the corresponding $\tan \beta$ can be expressed in closed-form (here the notation $2^{\alpha}||n$ means $2^{\alpha}|n$ and $2^{\alpha+1}\nmid n$).

Comment: Many thanks for the upvoter.